# Los Vaughts Test, why do we need out theory to be $\kappa$ Categorical

Tags: model-theory

I came across Los-Vaught's test:

> Let $\mathcal{L}$ be countable and $\Sigma$ a $\mathcal{L}$-theory. $\Sigma$ is complete, if
>
> 1. $\Sigma$ only has infinite models.
> 2. There is a cardinal number $\kappa$ for which any two models of cardinality $\kappa$ are isomorphic.

In the proof we use 2. just to get elementary equivalence:

> Let $A,B \in Mod (\Sigma)$, then $A \equiv A' \cong B' \equiv B$ hence $A \equiv B$.

Wouldn't it be enough to  just ask for elementary equivalence in the second statement?

Comment: You are correct, it would be enough. But in practice, the notion of $\kappa$-categoricity comes more often. I think there was a question on this site a while ago about whether your condition implied $\kappa$-categoricity.

Comment: @Max The question raised in your comment wouldn't make much sense: Any complete theory with infinite models satisfies the property that all models of size $\kappa$ are elementarily equiavlent (for every infinite $\kappa$), and of course this doesn't imply $\kappa$-categoricity. Is it possible you were thinking of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338439/are-there-any-non-trivially-potentially-categorical-first-order-theories)?

Comment: @AlexKruckman : you are of course right - I must misremember... but I don't think it was that question you linked to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. We can replace "all models of size $\kappa$ are isomorphic" with "all models of size $\kappa$ are elementarily equivalent" and everything goes through fine.